# TYPO3 Menu: Repeat parent link in first child

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to repeat the parent of a navigation as the first child of its child.
Example:

```
PARENT 1
-- Parent 1
-- Child 1
-- Child 2
---- Subchild 1
---- Subchild 2
-- Child 3
PARENT 2
-- Parent 2
-- Child 1
-- Child 2
-- Child 3
```

As this should only be the case in one menu, hence manually adding page links is not an option.

My current TypoScript is as follows.

```
lib.mainmenu = HMENU
lib.mainmenu {
  1 = TMENU
  1.expAll = 1
  1.NO.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
  1.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menuopener">|</li>
  1.ACT < .NO
  1.ACT = 1
  1.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menuopener active">|</li>

  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>

  3 < .1
  3.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  3.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  3.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `v:page.menu` as an alternative to TS based menu rendering? https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/Menu/DirectoryViewHelper.html - maybe as a starting point https://worksonmymachine.org/blog/a-guide-to-menu-rendering-with-fluidtypo3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found a solution, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089412/typo3-menu-duplicate-parent-link-on-submenu-list):

```
lib.mainmenu = HMENU
lib.mainmenu.entryLevel = 0
lib.mainmenu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {                                                                                                       
        expAll = 1
        NO {
            ATagTitle.field = title
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menuopener">|</li>
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            accessKey = 1
        }
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menuopener">|</li>
            linkWrap= |
            ATagParams = 
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }
        ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
        ACTIFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menuopener active">|</li>
        }
        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        }
        CURIFSUB < .IFSUB
        CURIFSUB = 1
        CURIFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        }
    }
    # second level
    2 = TMENU
    2.stdWrap.wrap.stdWrap.cObject = COA
    2.stdWrap.wrap.stdWrap.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.typolink.parameter = {field:pid}
        10.typolink.parameter.insertData = 1
        10.wrap = <ul><li>|</li>
        20 = TEXT
        20.value = |</ul>
    }
    2{
        expAll = 1
        NO{
            ATagTitle.field = title
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB{
            ATagTitle.field = title
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
    }

  3 < .1
  3.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  3.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  3.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
}
```